# How to repurpose(optimize) a left join statement?

Tags: pervasive, pervasive-sql

I have a query that is taking over 500 seconds to run. I managed to figure out the culprit to be my 2nd left join in the below query. When I comment out that left join, and the two columns I select from that table the query takes 3 seconds. When I run it as I need it, with nothing commented out, it takes over 500 seconds. Is there anyway to refactor the 2nd left join statement into this query? My guess is no but I had to try. This is pervasive and as far as I know the tables are indexed but not in any convenient way. Our vendor doesn't allow us to mess with the indexes either unfortunately. Any help is greatly appreciated! If all else fails, I think I will use a 2nd query in my php application to get the info I need.

#### Query

```
select concat(concat(job_header.job,'-'),job_header.suffix) as Job,job_header.part,job_header.qty_order,
 sum(case when job_operations_wc.workcenter = '0750' then job_operations_wc.hours_actual end) as WaterJet,
 sum(case when job_operations_wc.workcenter IN ('0705','0710','0715') then job_operations_wc.hours_actual end) as Laser,
 sum(case when job_operations_wc.workcenter = ('1006') then job_operations_wc.hours_actual end) as Prep,
 sum(case when job_operations_wc.workcenter IN ('1310','0755') then job_operations_wc.hours_actual end) as Machining,
 sum(case when job_operations_wc.workcenter IN ('1002','1003') then job_operations_wc.hours_actual end) as Fab,
 sum(case when job_operations_wc.workcenter = '1100' then job_operations_wc.hours_actual end) as Paint,
 sum(case when job_operations_wc.workcenter = '1000' then job_operations_wc.hours_actual end) as Belts,
 sum(case when job_operations_wc.workcenter = '1001' then job_operations_wc.hours_actual end) as Electrical,
 sum(case when job_operations_wc.workcenter = '1520' then job_operations_wc.hours_actual end) as Crating_Skids,
 sum(case when job_operations_wc.workcenter IN ('1004','1005','1350','1201') then job_operations_wc.hours_actual end) as Final_Assy,
 sum(job_operations_wc.hours_estimated) as total_hours_estimated
/* min(gab_source_cause_codes.source) as source,
min(gab_source_cause_codes.cause) as cause */
from job_header
left join job_operations_wc on job_operations_wc.job = job_header.job and job_header.suffix = job_operations_wc.suffix
/* left join gab_source_cause_codes on gab_source_cause_codes.job = job_operations_wc.job and gab_source_cause_codes.suffix = job_operations_wc.suffix and gab_source_cause_codes.seq = job_operations_wc.seq */
where job_header.product_line = '05' and job_header.date_closed > '000000' and job_operations_wc.LMO = 'L' and job_operations_wc.seq < '99000'
group by Job,job_header.part,job_header.qty_order
```

Comment: What does your query plan look like?  That will show what (if any indexes) are being used.   In the DDFs (using Control Center), are there indexes on job_header.job, job_header.suffix, job_operations_wc.suffix?  You might also look at the indexes for your WHERE clause and order them by fewest results since you're using AND in the WHERE.

Comment: @mirtheil I'm not familiar with a query plan. I looked through the documentation and executed the two statements to make a .qpf file. I found that you have to run the statements separately otherwise I get an error. Then I ran the query but I don't get the .qpf file created in the designated folder. I can however, look at the properties of the table and see the indexes. There are indexes on job_header_job, job_header.suffix and job_operations_wc.suffix. In the WHERE clause do you mean change the order they appear in that clause? or actually adding an ORDER BY clause?

Comment: On the WHERE clause, change the order of the restrictions.  If there are 10 records that match the "job_header.date_closed > '000000'" criteria and 100 records that match the "job_header.product_line = '05'" criteria, put the the restriction with fewer matches ("job_header.date_closed > '000000'") first.  The SQL engine will short circuit the AND statements.

Comment: A query plan, using Pervasive can be produced, see: [Query Plan Viewer](https://docs.actian.com/psql/psqlv11/sqlref/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=qpv.14.1.html).  The .qpf file is created on the server, not on the client.

Comment: Because you have this in your WHERE-clause: `job_operations_wc.LMO = 'L'   and job_operations_wc.seq < '99000'`, you can do an INNER JOIN (and not a LEFT JOIN) to `job_operations_wc`.   This alone can change your query speed, but you might even try to make `job_operations_wc` your main source, and then do a (INNER) JOIN to `job_header`.   I have seen query speed improving when starting from the table with most records.